# Split dataframe in multiple dataframes by NA rows

Tags: r, dataframe

1. problem explanation:

I have a dataframe (see sim.Dat.file6 in the code) which have numeric values and NA values, in an alternating way. I want to extract the numeric values in an individual dataframe and omit NA values.

2. My data:
   I simulate this data set in order to provide a clear and reproducible example in R.

```
#simulated data set:

set.seed(101)
x <- rep(factor(c(sample(c("a","b",3.5,"d","e","f","a1","b1",2.4,"d=",0,"f3"), 6), rnorm(c(1:6), 0.5, 0.1))),3)
y <- rep(factor(c(sample(c("a","b",3.5,"d","e","f","a1","b1",2.4,"d=",0,"f3"), 6), rnorm(c(1:6), 200, 5))),3)
z1 <- rep(factor(c(sample(c("a","b",3.5,"d","e","f","a1","b1",2.4,"d=",0,"f3"), 6), rep(0,6))),3)
z2  <- rep(factor(c(sample(c("a","b",3.5,"d","e","f","a1","b1",2.4,"d=",0,"f3"), 6),  rep(0,6))),3)

sim.Dat.file <- data.frame(x, y, z1, z2) 

sim.Dat.file2 <- sim.Dat.file[,-c(3:4)]

sim.Dat.file3 <- data.frame(Wavelength = as.numeric(paste(sim.Dat.file2$y)), Absorption = as.numeric(paste(sim.Dat.file2$x)))

#omit false Wavelength values 
allNA <-function(x) {
  
  if(x>180 | is.na(x)==TRUE){
    
    return(x)
    
  }else{
    
    x<-NA
  }
}

sim.Dat.file4 <-as.data.frame(sapply(sim.Dat.file3$Wavelength, allNA))

#omit false Absorption values 

allNA <-function(x) {
  
  if((x<1 & x>0)| is.na(x)==TRUE){
    
    return(x)
    
  }else{
    
    x<-NA
  }
}

sim.Dat.file5 <-as.data.frame(sapply(sim.Dat.file3$Absorption, allNA))

sim.Dat.file6 <-data.frame(sim.Dat.file4, sim.Dat.file5)
colnames(sim.Dat.file6) <-c("Absorption", "Wavelength")


#strategy1 
splitFUN <- function(x) {
  
  split(x, is.na(x==TRUE))
  
}

sim.Dat.file7 <- lapply(sim.Dat.file6, splitFUN)

#different spectra are merged together
```

And I stuck now, because `strsplit`  and `split`  don't work in my case, so far. If I use `split(df5, if.na(df5)==TRUE`  (shown in the code) I split in two groups NA values and numeric values (but I cannot divide them in separate spectra and plot each spectra individually). I changed NA values to characters and tried a `strsplit`, but this doesn't worked out properly as well.

```
#output of lapply-split extractet with dput
list(Absorption = list(`FALSE` = c(199.033310175013, 195.751226298331, 
200.292327489247, 195.91164822062, 189.748460921802, 199.181221670293, 
199.033310175013, 195.751226298331, 200.292327489247, 195.91164822062, 
189.748460921802, 199.181221670293, 199.033310175013, 195.751226298331, 
200.292327489247, 195.91164822062, 189.748460921802, 199.181221670293
), `TRUE` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), 
    Wavelength = list(`FALSE` = c(0.53107692173136, 0.61739662875627, 
    0.561878985562597, 0.488726568524579, 0.591702828951271, 
    0.477674063537274, 0.53107692173136, 0.61739662875627, 0.561878985562597, 
    0.488726568524579, 0.591702828951271, 0.477674063537274, 
    0.53107692173136, 0.61739662875627, 0.561878985562597, 0.488726568524579, 
    0.591702828951271, 0.477674063537274), `TRUE` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)))
```

3. The aim of data transformation:

I want to automatize the extraction of numeric values out of the dataset. The extracted values should be added after each other in a dataframe or each set of numeric extracted values should be saved in an individual dataframe. In this case the optimal output would be

```
output.data.frame <- data.frame(spectra1= sim.Dat.file6[7:12,], spectra2= sim.Dat.file6[19:24,], spectra3= sim.Dat.file6[31:36,])
output.data.frame
   spectra1.Absorption spectra1.Wavelength spectra2.Absorption spectra2.Wavelength spectra3.Absorption
7             199.0333           0.5310769            199.0333           0.5310769            199.0333
8             195.7512           0.6173966            195.7512           0.6173966            195.7512
9             200.2923           0.5618790            200.2923           0.5618790            200.2923
10            195.9116           0.4887266            195.9116           0.4887266            195.9116
11            189.7485           0.5917028            189.7485           0.5917028            189.7485
12            199.1812           0.4776741            199.1812           0.4776741            199.1812
   spectra3.Wavelength
7            0.5310769
8            0.6173966
9            0.5618790
10           0.4887266
11           0.5917028
12           0.4776741
```

Comment: you need to provide a much shorter, clearer and reproducible example that we can copy/paste on our side for us to help you. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @CatalystRPA  is the above example okay from your point of view (or still too long, not clear). Should I add some further information. Thank you in advance for helping me with this issue.

Comment: @RonakShah It is better but still needs more clarity. Can you please articulate you question like this: 1. explanation of the problem (without any domain-specific information) 2.This is my data 3. This is my expected result. Here is is hard to know what you want to do because we don't have expected results. Keep in mind we can only help you on the coding and data part, we are not experts in physics, sensors or wavelengths.

Comment: @CatalystRPA: I updated the question. Hopefully, now, in a more appropriate style.

Comment: good edits for a start, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that the below does what you want in a quite simpler way.

```
res_wave <- sim.Dat.file3$Wavelength[!is.na(sim.Dat.file3$Wavelength)]
res_abso <- sim.Dat.file3$Absorption[!is.na(sim.Dat.file3$Absorption)]
result <- data.frame(res_wave, res_abso)
> head(result)
  res_wave  res_abso
1   0.0000 2.4000000
2 199.0333 0.5310769
3 195.7512 0.6173966
4 200.2923 0.5618790
5 195.9116 0.4887266
6 189.7485 0.5917028
```

The NA values are filtered out using the idiom `x[!is.na(x)]`. By the way it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with your functions

```
testfunction <-function(x) {
  if((x<1 & x>0)| is.na(x)){
    print("condition is true on first element")
    return(x)
  }else{
    print("condition is false on first element")
    x<-NA
  }
}
testdata1 <- c(0.5,1,NA)
testdata2 <- c(999,1,NA)
testfunction(testdata1)
# > testfunction(testdata1)
# [1] "condition is true on first element"
# [1] 0.5 1.0  NA
# Warning message:
#   In if ((x < 1 & x > 0) | is.na(x)) { :
#       the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

# testfunction(testdata2)
# [1] "condition is false on first element"
# Warning message:
#   In if ((x < 1 & x > 0) | is.na(x)) { :
#       the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This function will return either the same vector (***all*** its original values) passed as parameter if its ***first*** element satisfies your condition.

If the first element does not satisfy your condition, it will return ***nothing*** but executes `x<-NA` which would change ***all*** the values within `x` to `NA`.

Excepted that in this case it does ***not*** change the object because you are changing `x` inside the function environment and not in the global environment. As you can see below, `data2` remains unchanged because it was only changed within the function.

```
> testdata2
[1] 999   1  NA
```

In order to modify an object in the `.Globalenv()` from within a function, you can use `<<-` instead of `<-` however here I think the problem is that you are not aware of the vectorized aspect of R.

if data1 is a `vector`, `data1 > 0` will return a ***VECTOR*** of `TRUE`, `FALSE` values with the same length as `data1`. but the `if` statement only takes the ***first*** of these boolean values into account.

Try to look at my solution and undertand how it works. As you can see vectorization in R allows you to bypass the need for many loops and functions.

Comment: I understand the first code part, but I dont want to have values like 0 or 2.4 (see first row of your solution) . I wrote the functions to separate all true measurement values >180 for "Wavelength" and between 0 and 1 for "Absorption" from "false" values, which exist between NA values. Further, if I use this functions in combinations with sapply or lapply, it works. Do you have in general the same output as me, when you copy the code to your IDE? And how I could automatize the extraction of numeric values like I shown in (3.The aims of transformation)?

Comment: I understand your point with if function. But i wanted to avoid for or while iteration through a dataframe column. So it was okay for me that the conditions were working only for the first element of the vector. If I use than sapply to a certain column, than I ask for each element e.g. if this element is higher than 180 or it is NA value than don't change the value, if it is for example 0 or 2.4 (like in the first row of your solution) than change this values to NA (because those values are false). Is this a bad coding practice in R to combine if-based functions with sapply or lapply?